Annotate with Segment Anything Model (SAM) - Unhealty
I have been using CVAT with the SAM component for some time. I've never had any major problems until today.
I inserted a new button with images that have a name 64 characters long between numbers and letters, with a Jpg extension. After I import and start using SAM on this images - the component fails.
In the CLIO console the SAM status is Unhealty
Is it possible that images with a long name could cause problems?
I tried with other images of the same kb size and format and found no problems. Is it possible that SAM doesn't handle this type of name length?
